# postgresql recovery.conf file location in 11.5

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-11

I'm new to postgres. We need to take incremental backups for postgres databases as well as we must be able to perform PITR. I searched a lot on internet and tried to find out any article referencing method for incremental + PITR for postgres 11.5. However, I couldn't find much and found https://www.scalingpostgres.com/tutorials/postgresql-backup-point-in-time-recovery/

meaningful. I started working around the steps mentioned there. However at #add recovery.conf

```
    # add recovery.conf
    nano /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf
```

The article says to create the recovery.conf in main directory. However, as per 11.5 installation, there is no main directory. The directory structure is like:

```
    /var/lib/pgsql/11/data
    [root@local-pos-52 data]# ls -ltr
      total 96
      -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 23971 Aug 30 16:05 postgresql.conf
      drwx------. 6 postgres postgres    50 Aug 30 16:07 base
      -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4370 Aug 30 16:12 pg_hba.conf
       drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30 16:12 pg_replslot
       drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Aug 30 19:04 pg_notify
       -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    58 Aug 30 19:04 postmaster.opts
       -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    30 Aug 30 19:04 current_logfiles
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30 19:04 pg_stat
        drwx------. 4 postgres postgres    65 Aug 30 19:04 pg_logical
        drwx------. 3 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 30 19:04 pg_wal
       -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    96 Aug 30 19:04 postmaster.pid
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 30 19:04 global
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    60 Aug 30 19:19 pg_stat_tmp
        -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     3 Aug 30  2019 PG_VERSION
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_twophase
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_tblspc
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_snapshots
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_serial
        drwx------. 4 postgres postgres    34 Aug 30  2019 pg_multixact
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_dynshmem
        drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Aug 30  2019 pg_commit_ts
        -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 23891 Aug 30  2019 postgresql.conf- 
       bak
       -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    88 Aug 30  2019 
       postgresql.auto.conf
       -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 Aug 30  2019 pg_ident.conf
      -rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4269 Aug 30  2019 pg_hba.conf-bak
       drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Aug 30  2019 pg_xact
       drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Aug 30  2019 pg_subtrans
       drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    31 Aug 30  2019 log
```

Also, there is no folder named "postgresql" got created in this installation at /var/lib location.

I tried to go with creating recovery.conf at this path "/var/lib/pgsql/11/data" only. However, after that when I restarted postgres services,it didn't work.

It will be appreciated ,if someone specifies where to create  recovery.conf, so that it will actually work or share the doc/link to implement incremental backups as well as PITR for postgres 11.5

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you get by following tutorials. It is better to understand the process (as explained in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY)), then problems like this won't happen.

You have to place `recovery.conf` in the *data directory*. The data directory is the directory where `postgresql.conf` is, **unless** the `data_directory` parameter in `postgresql.conf` says differently.

Comment: Hi @laurenz albe , thanks for sharing this doc. It was really helpful. Do you have any another step by step doc to implement PITR and incremental backups?

Comment: Don't look for cookbooks, try to *understand* the procedure. Knowledge is power.

Comment: I agree with you @laurenz . However, still whenever I place recovery.conf into data directory,my postgresql services aren't starting again.

Comment: Investigate! Look at the error messages!